# Do I need a visa for a 3-day stopover in the Republic of Korea?

Tags: south-korea, stopovers, vietnamese-citizens

I'm flying from Canada and I'm currently holding a Vietnamese passport with a Canadian student visa. Am I allowed to enter Korea during a stopover, or do I need a visa to enter?

Comment: I did an edit, as period of 3 days is not considered a layover, but a break in the journey.

Comment: @Giorgio I appreciate that! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passport doesn't get you a visa waiver, but your Canadian visa does, if you are flying from or to Canada, which seems to be your case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea#30-day_visa_exemption

Comment: By the link you gave, I can possibly enter Korea without Korean visa.

Comment: That's what I'm saying...

Answer (score 1):

Per Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Viet Nam with a visa
>   issued by Australia, Austria, Belgium, **Canada**, Cyprus, Czech
>   Rep., Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece,
>   Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia,
>   Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New
>   Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia,
>   Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom if
>   in transit through Korea (Rep.) must
>
> -hold confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within
>     30 days when
>     arriving from the country that issued the visa and
>     departing to a third Country

So no, you do **not** need a visa